# ssrs : table of contents with links which render to pdf

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

in ssrs 2008, i am trying to create a table of contents page which when exported to pdf will have links to relevent subreport. I am able to create a document map but that just appears on the side....would like to have table of contents with links.

thks
ken

Comment: If you have multiple tables/matrixes then the TOC should see this as an entry.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple tables/matrixes then the TOC should see this as an entry

grp1TextBoxTitle

```
CustomProperties="1 Group Header"
DocumentMapLabel="1 Group Header"
```

grp2TextBoxTitle

```
CustomProperties="2 Group Header"
DocumentMapLabel="2 Group Header"
```

In which case:

Excel will see the DocumentMapLabel property as a toc link and and PDF will see CustomProperties as a toc link.